# Excepción del código de estado de blazor httpClient.PostJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Cuando utilizo HtttpCliente en mi aplizacion de Blazor server app, al momento de utilizar el evento para Log in con PostJsonAsyn me aparece  un error en la consola del navegador (aclaro que en mi pagina de login no me aparece ningun error a nivel codigo, solo eso me pasa cuando intento hacer el loguea de una persona en mi app de blazor)

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.SendJsonAsync[T](HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod method, String requestUri, Object content) at arathsbaby_web.Pages.Users.Login.ValidateUser() in C:\Users\81416\Desktop\ArathsBaby-master\ArathsBaby\frontend\arathsbaby_web\Pages\Users\Login.razor:line 56 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)`

Este seria mi evento, en el cual se utiliza PostJsonAsync para mandar la respuesta, pero no funciona (intente con usar PostAsJson pero me marcaba un error con mi objeto userInfo ya que no se puede convertir a int)

```
    private async Task<bool> ValidateUser()
{
    //string endpoint = $"{baseUrl}api/Users/Login";

    var rpta = await Http.PostJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo); <-- aqui seria en donde me marca el error en la consola del navegador

    //PostAsJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

    if (rpta !=0)
    {
        ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)auth).UserLogin(rpta.ToString());
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("catalog");
    }
    else
    {
        LoginMesssage = "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Este seria mi controlador para que el usuario se logue (no estoy utilizando nada de Identity ni los token ya que me llevaria un poco mas de tiempo en terminar el proyecto)

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Accont/Login")]
    public int Login([FromBody] UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        int rpta = 0;
        int nvces;
        try
        {
            using (ArathsBabyContext db = new ArathsBabyContext())
            {
                nvces = db.Users.Where(p => p.Email == userInfo.Email
                 && p.Password == userInfo.Password).Count();
                if (nvces == 0)
                {
                    rpta = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nvces = db.Users.Where(p => p.Email == userInfo.Email
                 && p.Password == userInfo.Password).First().Id;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rpta = 0;
        }

        return rpta;
    }
```

Tambien intente utilizando lo que es SendJsonAsync, pensando en que asi el errro se podria correguir pero cuando intento loguearme a mi app me aparecio el siguiente error en la consola del navegador.

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.SendJsonAsync[T](HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod method, String requestUri, Object content) at arathsbaby_web.Pages.Users.Login.ValidateUser() in C:\Users\81416\Desktop\ArathsBaby-master\ArathsBaby\frontend\arathsbaby_web\Pages\Users\Login.razor:line 57 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)`

Y asi tendria el evento con SendJsonAsync

```
 private async Task<bool> ValidateUser()
{
    string endpoint = $"{baseUrl}api/Users/Login";

    var rpta = await Http.SendJsonAsync<int>(HttpMethod.Post,endpoint,userInfo);
        
    //PostJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

    //PostAsJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

    if (rpta !=0)
    {
        ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)auth).UserLogin(rpta.ToString());
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("catalog");
    }
    else
    {
        LoginMesssage = "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Lo que yo quisera saber es por que lo que es PostJsonAsync no me funciona en mi App de blazor, no se si se deba a que me falte algun tipo de libreria o por que es que me da ese error.

Comment: Trataste de usar Postman para ver si el problema esta en tu metodo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en que no recibes el int puro y por ello no lo puedes procesar.
Aqui se presentan 2 problemas:

1. Si no recibes int, que haces?
2. Es posible que servidor no capta mi petición y no me responde?

En cualquier caso, lo mejor seria primero verificar que es lo que te responde el servidor y como lo hace y luego ya intentar procesar la respuesta.

Podrias adaptar este codigo a tus necesidades:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int>();
}
return null;
```

Como puedes observar, primero verificamos la respuesta y luego la intentamos procesar. Podriamos hacer lo con mas comprobaciones y poner le un try/catch en caso de una respuesta no int, pero esto no es muy necesario, ya que si controlas los dos lados, tanto cliente como servidor, siempre sabes que si servidor te responde bien, pues recibes un int. Si API REST que consultas no es tuyo, no puedes fiar 100% de que siempre vas a recibir int, en este caso mejor seria añadir una verificación adicional despues de recibir bien la respuesta.